# Linux authentication

Tags: linux, authentication

Does linux support a replacement of its username/password collection UI in x-windows.  To specify, I have a windows authentication method that uses gina/credential providers to display an alternative to the usual username and password.  I wish to port this to linux.

I realise that text-mode runlevels will not support this, and only x-windows would.

Comment: Is it something that could be supported by PAM, or is it a whole new GUI? Please give a better explanation of what you're trying to do.

Comment: AFAICT, Xwindows doesn't have any username/passowrd ui.  you must be talking about the session manager, which is a very small program included with any DE; but they're very interchangeable

Comment: This would be a new GUI that would, at the end of the process, present for authentication the same username and password as would be normally.

Comment: You are aware that, even with X Windows, there is no single unified login interface?  XDM, KDM, GDM, Entrance, SLiM, etc. all provide different interfaces for graphical logins.  (Heck, even at the console, there's more available than just the traditional getty+`/bin/login`, like Qingy.)  At the very least, KDM supports pluggable greeters...  anyhow, it really does sound like you want to write a PAM module, not replace the interface?

Answer (score 0):

> Does linux support a replacement of its username/password collection UI in x-windows.

Yes.  All the components are open source, and if you're lucky don't need much modification.  PAM = Pluggable Authentication Modules, and then you need a GUI like GDM/KDM/XDM to collect whatever you need to pass to pam for authentication.

This is basically what everyone has already told you in comments...